# Android 3: Simulating the behaviour of a soft-keyboard for a virtual piano keyboard

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, view

I work on a synthesizer where I would like to have a keyboard/piano displayed that the user can toggle on or off in any activity of the synthesizer to play keys. The best solution would be if it would behave like the normal softkeyboard, that means, I would like the "virtual piano" to resize the current activity to be a little bit smaller in it's height, so that the keyboard doesn't occupy relevant areas (every activity is already vertically scrollable).

I searched the docs but didn't find any elegant solution to this. Any hints?

Thanks!

Nils

Comment: You always have the option of looking at the code of the normal softkeyboard, as it is available at the android site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the Activity attributes in AndroidManiFest file

like

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"></activity>
```